# Session State in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How can we access the Session variable in a Sharepoint 2010 sandboxed solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Session variable is apparently one of the things that is specifically unavailable in the sandbox.

If you really need access to it then you should consider using an non-sandbox solution, the pros and cons of which are discussed here:
[Sandbox solutions seem to be too severely crippled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565794/sandbox-solutions-seem-to-be-too-severely-crippled)

Comment: is there any alternative for the same?

Comment: @Anoop George Thomas: None that I'm aware of. And the lack of alternative answers seems to indicate not. You could try reposting here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/